# How to update time zone file tzdata on Android 8

Tags: android, timezone, tzdata

Many countries don't go by daylight saving anymore such as Chile and Lebanon. How do I update the tzdata file in /system/usr/share/zoneinfo? I need to compile it using the NDK and replace any existing files related to time zone.

I tried downloading tzupdater apk but that didn't work. It says

> > > TIME ZONE DATABASE
> > > Getting latest version ... fail
> > > An error has occurred. Existing.

Answer (score 2):

This question is more fit for [Android Stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com).

1. You need to have root access to your phone since you need to modify system files.
2. You need to build updated tzdata file using `android_system_timezone` ([LineageOS version](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_system_timezone/tree/lineage-15.1)), it might be needed to download android build toolchain for your specific android version.
   Note that there is an already built tzdata available at the repository, you can use it if its version already contains your required time zone updates.
3. take a **backup** of your current `tzdata` and `tz_version` (not sure about `tz_version` in android 8) and replace them with the one that you have built at step 2.

path of tzdata:

```
Android pre 10 /system/usr/share/zoneinfo/

later versions /system/apex/com.android.tzdata/etc/tz/
```